# Spring Boot 3.0 + AKS = always 200 with empty response

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure-aks, istio-gateway

I'm asking for your help for a very strange situation I'm having, after upgrading a microservice to Spring Boot 3.0, from 2.7.x version.

The microservice is deployed on AKS cluster, and, when I invoke any endpoint exposed by the microservice from the context-root, **with any cookie**, i always obtain a http status code 200 - OK with empty response, instead of the response i expect; this also happens to me when i invoke endpoints not exposed by the microservice. If instead I invoke the same endpoints **without cookies**, everything works correctly.

However, when I test the microservice endpoints locally (start in local debug) with new Spring Boot version (3.0.0) or when I rollback the microservice to the previous Spring Boot version (2.7.x) and deploy it on AKS cluster, everything works fine, both with and without cookies.

So I don't understand if the "problem" is on Spring Boot framework update or AKS/istio (kube ingress).

Here are some examples for clarity:

```
curl --request GET --url http://localhost:8080/endpoint -H "cookie: key=test"
{"out": "value"}

curl --request GET --url http://localhost:8080/endpoint
{"out": "value"}
```

this is OK!

```
curl --request GET --url http://my.ingress.com/context-root/endpoint -H "cookie: key=test"
(200 with empty response)

curl --request GET --url http://my.ingress.com/context-root/endpoint
{"out": "value"}
```

this is *strange*!

You are my last hope! :D
Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We ran into the same issue last week, but with an ECS cluster. Do you happen to have a [DataDog tracing agent](https://github.com/DataDog/dd-trace-java) being deployed alongside your service? Someone had a [similar issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/33735) and their solution was to [bump the agent version to 1.3.0](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/33735#issuecomment-1378320002). We bumped our agent to 1.4.0 and that fixed our issue.

The root cause could probably be traced back to [this change](https://github.com/DataDog/dd-trace-java/pull/4304) if I had to guess

Comment: Hi Henry :D
Yessss, I also have a DataDog tracking agent distributed with my service.
I'll immediately try to update the agent to version 1.4.0 and let you know, but I'd say you've caught the problem!!

I do not know how to thank you! You are my savior :D

Comment: Great!! It worked! Tell me how I can pay you at least one coffee

Comment: xD, no worries, spreading the word about the fix whenever you see someone else facing a similar issue is good enough for me :)